# Execute console command and get its output

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm wondering, in Visual Basic 2008, how to execute an external console (commandline) command and get its output without help of an intermediate file (to speed up)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at [ProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput.aspx) and [Process.StandardOutput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput(v=VS.90).aspx).

Example:

```
compiler.StartInfo.FileName = "csc.exe"
compiler.StartInfo.Arguments = "/r:System.dll /out:sample.exe stdstr.cs"
compiler.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
compiler.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
compiler.Start()

Console.WriteLine(compiler.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd())

compiler.WaitForExit()
```

Comment: Hi dtb,
Thanks for your reply.

I think it works well. The only thing is that it will pop up a command window till the external command ends. How can I suppress this window? Thanks

Comment: I just got it:
compiler.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True