# How to run a batch file within a C# GUI form

Tags: c#, .net, windows

How would you execute a batch script within a GUI form in C#

Could anyone provide a sample please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This example assumes a Windows Forms application with two text boxes (`RunResults` and `Errors`).

```
// Remember to also add a using System.Diagnostics at the top of the class
private void RunIt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (Process p = new Process())
    {
        p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "<path to batch file folder>";
        p.StartInfo.FileName = "<path to batch file itself>";
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        p.Start();
        p.WaitForExit();

        // Capture output from batch file written to stdout and put in the 
        // RunResults textbox
        string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(output) && output.Trim() != "")
        {
            this.RunResults.Text = output;
        }

        // Capture any errors written to stderr and put in the errors textbox.
        string errors = p.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(errors) & errors.Trim() != ""))
        {
            this.Errors.Text = errors;
        }
    }
}
```

**Updated:**

The sample above is a button click event for a button called `RunIt`. There's a couple of text boxes on the form, `RunResults` and `Errors` where we write the results of `stdout` and `stderr` to.

Comment: @Kev Hi, thank you, how would this be initialized though in for example a text box?

Comment: @Kev, Hi, yes that is thank you, I have done as its written, although I get some compile errors, I think this might be because I am using NET framework 3.5 / VS 2008 (will try upgrading..),

Comment: @Kev just got it sorted, a few mistakes on my part! Thanks for your help

Comment: @Mike - updated to make it .NET 3.5 friendly. `IsNullOrWhiteSpace` is a new method added to .NET Framework 4.0.

Answer (score 5):

[System.Diagnotics.Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx)("yourbatch.bat"); ought to do it.

[Another thread covering the same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541087/execute-dos-command-and-get-its-output).

Comment: @Will A Hi, thank you for the prompt reply, although how would you implement it into a form?

Comment: @Mike - exactly as written, Mike - or do you actually want to run the batch file and have the output displayed within UI on the form?

Comment: @Will A Yes I would like the output displayed within the UI on the form

Comment: @Mike - take a look at this, albeit for VB.Net.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541087/execute-dos-command-and-get-its-output

Comment: I'm guessing this article: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/Execute_Command_in_CSharp.aspx will just about cover it...

Comment: @Will A Cheers, I will take a look

Answer (score 1):

I deduce that by *executing within a GUI form* you mean showing execution results within some UI-Control.

Maybe something like this:

```
private void runSyncAndGetResults_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)     
{
    System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi =
       new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\batch.bat");

    psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    psi.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    psi.UseShellExecute = false;

    System.Diagnostics.Process batchProcess;
    batchProcess = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(psi);

    System.IO.StreamReader myOutput = batchProcess.StandardOutput;
    batchProcess.WaitForExit(2000);
    if (batchProcess.HasExited)
    {
        string output = myOutput.ReadToEnd();

        // Print 'output' string to UI-control
    }
}
```

Example taken from [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/06/01/146375.aspx).

Comment: how would you call on this function for example from a button?